# Does hajj become compulsory if you perform um-rah?

Tags: umrah

Some people says that after performing um-rah it is compulsory to perform hajj. But some people says that it is not compulsory.So anyone can guide me.

Comment: Hajj is compulsory and 'Umrah optional... By logic which of both should you do if able to?

Answer (score 1):

haj is obligatory one time in a life if you have enough financial resources so it is better to perform first haj then umrah.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform um-rah when you able to bear financial experiences and Yes haj is compulsory if you are financially stable to do it.

Answer (score -1):

The **5 pillars** of Islam are:

```
Kalma Taiyeba ; Namaz ; Roza ; Hajj  ;Zakat
```

means Hajj is basic Pillar of Islam; Umrah is not a complete Hajj; although the way to perform both are same but not completely same.
So its not right to say(that it is not compulsory)
unless financial or health issues as per as I learn